# Ruby Thin web server - unresponsive site when using rails_admin to upload thumbnail image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ssl

I recently picked up a RoR project using Thin as its web server running on Windows Server 2012.

Whenever I go to the admin section of this site and upload a thumbnail image (or export data) then save its related task, I'm greeted with approximately a two minute wait before the "save" action completes.  However, this doesn't only briefly pause the admin panel, it also blocks the rest of the site including the home page from loading.

I know that Thin is an evented server; however, I've already tried --threaded without success (entirely possible that I used it incorrectly).  What stumps me is that I've also tested this locally on my MacBook running on OSX El Cap without issue.  Additionally, it runs on my colleague's machine locally on Windows 7.  It's only when I deploy to our Windows Server 2012 environment when I'm encountering this problem.

Here is the command line argument I use to run (I took out the threaded option for now):
'thin start -p ""%1"" --ssl --ssl-disable-verify -e production'

I'm thinking it could possibly be a firewall issue, but since I don't have direct access to the server it's harder to diagnose.  I'm also thinking it could be a blocking issue caused by Thin since the entire site appears to get hung up on the save action.  Aside from that, image size is irrelevant - the site gets hung up for pretty much exactly two minutes no matter if the pic is small or extremely large.  I've also monitored the system's performance to make sure there isn't an issue where the server was getting bogged down, but that's not the case here.

Any ideas?

Comment: Didn't experienced similar issue with thin (now in 1.6.4 version). Several MiBs uploads per second from multiple clients represent no problem. However this is on BSD platform. I'd make sure correct ruby/rack/thin builds are used, trying upload through plain http, run thin in a debugging mode. The threaded mode is enough to run with `--threaded` option, no other actions are required.

Comment: Thanks @joanbm.  I've been checking the logs but everything looks good - no errors, and the behavior is what I'd expect, which is what makes this such a puzzling issue.  Definitely partly attribute this to running on a Windows Server instead of a *nix system.